# itextsharp measure chunk width / height

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to do some precise alignment with iTextSharp, but I keep falling short as I can't figure out a way to get a width / height value for a chunk or paragraph.    If I create a paragraph that is  a certain font and size and text, then its dimensions should be known, right?

I know that the default left/right/center alignments will do the trick for me mostly, but I have scenarios where knowing the dimensions will be most useful.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get a chunk's width using `GetWidthPoint()` and the height of a chunk is generally the font's size unless you're using only lowercase letters. If so then you can manually measure characters using `BaseFont.GetCharBBox()`.

Paragraphs are flowable items, however, and they depend on the context that they are written into so measuring them is harder. (Chunks don't automatically wrap but Paragraphs do.) The best way to measure a paragraph is to write it to a `PdfCell` and then measure the `PdfCell`. You don't have to actually add the `PdfCell` to the document. The link below explains it a little more.

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Linecount-td2146114.html

Comment: Thanks, I also found out how to get the correct height measurement.  BaseFont.GetAscentPoint() - BaseFont.GetDescentPoint().  Maybe you can add this to your answer so it is a little more together.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might also be able to use a `ColumnText`'s `go(false)`, but I'm not sure that would get you the width, just the height.

Comment: The ColumnText.go(false) really is more useful if you only care if text fits (if that is what you are doing, it's actually easier than measuring)

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for exact size

```
Font font = ...;
BaseFont baseFont = font.BaseFont;
float width = baseFont.GetWidthPoint(text, fontSize);
float height = baseFont.GetAscentPoint(text, fontSize) - baseFont.GetDescentPoint(text, fontSize);
```