# iTextSharp Determine rectangle size of dynamic text

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I want to write direct content on to the top (in front of or preceding) an imported PDF.  I don't want to over write any of the text on the imported page.  I'm trying to create the NEW pdf with enough space at the top to imbed the text and then place the imported image beneath it.  Is there a way to see how much length I would need to add to a custom document page size give the known width of the page and length of the imported PDF? 
In other words, I want to embed "This is important information about the PDF below" and know how much additional page length to add in addition to the existing PDF so it's all on one page.

Comment: So you're trying to measure a string? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091540/itextsharp-measure-chunk-width-height

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think the OP also wants to know where to put that text, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143938/find-location-last-object-on-pdf-page-using-itextsharp In any case: the question is misleading because of the use word of the ambiguous `dynamic` (dynamic often refers to forms, as in dynamic XFA,...).