# Define the size of iTextSharp Textfield based on how much content a user inputs in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, textfield, autoresize

I was not able to find any overflow posts about resizing or readjusting iTextSharp's Text Field based on the user's input content they have in C#. I was hoping if anybody can help me here as this has been proving rather difficult for me.

Here is what I want to accomplish. Based on the user's amount of text input, I want to be able to have iTextSharp's Text Field size to be readjustable without have the text content be wrapped or resize font size at the end of the textbox.

Here is the block of code that I have for a textbox so far:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;


string bodyText = "This is the text that the user inputs. I want the textfield to resize ";
       bodyText += "based on how much text content there is here. I do not want the ";
       bodyText += "text to wrap around or shrink text size at the end of the textfield.";

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strPDFpath, FileMode.Create));
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
TextField _subject = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(103f, 485f, 503, 499f), "tfSubject");
     //I want this Rectangle size to be readjustable based on the text content but
     //I'm not sure how to do that.

_subject.FontSize = 10f;
_subject.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
_subject.Text = bodyText;
writer.AddAnnotation(_subject.GetTextField());
cb = writer.DirectContent;
```

Not only that, after the textfield has been resized, I want to be able to add static text right under the resized textfield. This proves to be quite tricky since the textfield is set at absolute positioning.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the title, you claim that you want to *re*size a text field, which implies that you have an existing PDF with an existing text field. In the body of the question, you create a text field as if you're creating a document from scratch. What is it that you want? Do you want to *re*size an existing text field or define the size of a new text field?

Comment: I want to define the size of the new text field based on the string content that the user will input.

Comment: Ultimately you want to [measure a string based on a given font and size, right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5092566/231316)? That link should get you most there, you just need to account for the widget's padding which is application-dependent but you can fudge some numbers that probably works in most places.

Comment: Or, if you're talking about a multi-line text field, you could use `ColumnText` to create a rectangle with a fixed width, add content, and then ask the column how much height was "consumed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at the answer to this question: [Add PdfPCell to Paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247348/add-pdfpcell-to-paragraph)

In this answer, we create a form that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the size of the form fields differs depending on the length of the content we're expecting.

How is this done? That's easy: we use `Chunk` objects with generic tag events to add the fields. See the [GenericFields](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/creating-form-fields#1327-genericfields.java) example:

```
public class FieldChunk extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    @Override
    public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
        TextField field = new TextField(writer, rect, text);
        try {
            writer.addAnnotation(field.getTextField());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ex);
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet is written in Java, but it should be fairly easy to port it to C# (just pretend that I wrote pseudo-code if you don't know Java).

We can use the page event like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    writer.setPageEvent(new FieldChunk());
    document.open();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.add("The Effective Date is ");
    Chunk day = new Chunk("     ");
    day.setGenericTag("day");
    p.add(day);
    p.add(" day of ");
    Chunk month = new Chunk("     ");
    month.setGenericTag("month");
    p.add(month);
    p.add(", ");
    Chunk year = new Chunk("            ");
    year.setGenericTag("year");
    p.add(year);
    p.add(" that this will begin.");
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, the length of the field is determined by the number of spaces we introduce in the `Chunk`:

```
Chunk day   = new Chunk("     ");
Chunk month = new Chunk("     ");
Chunk year  = new Chunk("            ");
```

The more spaces, the wider the field.

Using `Chunk`s will make it much easier for you to introduce extra static content under each field.

For multi-line text fields, I would suggest to use a `PdfPTable` and a cell event. Adding a field in a table cell is demonstrated in the examples [Create fields in a table](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/create-fields-table) on the [official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/).